# Play music from the default music service from a custom skill in Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there a way to ask the default music service to play music from my custom skill?
For example, if a user asks "Alexa, ask superalarm to wake me up in the morning with Travis Scott song."

Comment: This question doesn't relate to programming as such, and isn't meant for stackoverflow

Comment: Im looking for any API or library method for my custom skill for Amazon Alexa on node.js on Amazon Lambda.

Comment: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/music-skills/understand-the-music-skill-api.html Something similar but about communication between custom skills